# Orientação a Objetos minha idéia de conexão está correto?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu quero cadastrar algo no banco usando PHP orientado a objetos(estou aprendendo na verdade) e me deparei com um problema de duplicação de código(toda função eu teria que criar um novo mysqli, e ver se consigo conectar.

Então, criei uma função para conectar que retorna um objeto mysqli.

```
class banco{
private const host = "host";
private const banco = "nome_do_banco";
private const user = "meu_usuario";
private const password = "minha_senha";

public function conectar(){
 $conectar-> new mysqli(self::host,self::user,self:password);
 if($conectar->connect_error){
  die('Falha na conexão:'.$conectar->connect_error);
 }
 return $conectar;
}

public function cadastrar($produto, $preco){
 $conectar = this->conectar();
 $sql = 'insert into '.self::banco.'.produto(produto,preco) value("'.$produto.'","'.$preco.'");';
 if($conectar->query($sql) === TRUE){
   return 'cadastrado';
 }else{
   return 'Erro: '.$conectar->error;
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, mas da pra melhorar,

1. Toda vez que você chama `this->conectar()` para obter uma nova conexão, você cria uma nova instância do objeto de conexão com o banco, então, em determinado momento da aplicação, você precisa executar 3 querys e vai ser criada 3 conexões com o mesmo banco
2. Ao instanciar a classe `mysqli`, você pode passar o nome do banco no quarto parâmetro, assim não precisa adicionar o banco a cada query (`INSERT INTO my_db.my_table ...`)
3. Nessa classe você tem duas funções, uma que conecta e outra que realiza o cadastro de um produto, mas e o cadastro de usuários? Teria que misturar as funções de produtos e usuários ou criar uma nova classe e repetir a função de conexão

Código com mais algumas ideias de melhorias:

```
class Banco {
    private const host = "host";
    private const banco = "nome_do_banco";
    private const user = "meu_usuario";
    private const password = "minha_senha";

    private static $conexao = null;

    public static function conectar(){
        if (self::$conexao != null) {
            return self::$conexao;
        }

        self::$conexao = new mysqli(self::host,self::user,self::password, self::banco);

        if(self::$conexao->connect_error){
            die('Falha na conexão:'.self::$conexao->connect_error);
        }

        return self::$conexao;
    }
}

class Produto extends Banco {
    public function cadastrar($produto, $preco){
        $conectar = self::conectar();

        $sql = 'insert into produto(produto,preco) value("'.$produto.'","'.$preco.'");';

        if($conectar->query($sql) === TRUE){
            return 'cadastrado';
        }else{
            return 'Erro: '.$conectar->error;
        }
    }
}

class Usuario extends Banco {
    public function cadastrar($nome, $idade){
        $conectar = self::conectar();

        $sql = 'insert into usuario(nome,idade) value("'.$nome.'","'.$idade.'");';

        if($conectar->query($sql) === TRUE){
            return 'cadastrado';
        }else{
            return 'Erro: '.$conectar->error;
        }
    }
}
```

Imagino que está começando a programar em PHP, então recomendo dar uma olhada na [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) que é um guia de estilo de codificação  e nessa pergunta do SOpt sobre [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864)

Comment: No caso na classe produto é `$conectar = self::conectar();`? Não seria `$conectar = this->conectar();`?

Comment: Ambos funcionam, não é necessário usar o `this` porque o método é estático, mas se quiser funcionará igual